# Find Min DateTime and Assign DateTime to Local Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get the minimum datetime, then the maximum datetime and compare the two. But, I get the following error when I try to extract the DateTime values from the LINQ. Any help will be appreciated.

The error is thrown on this line: appChartDateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dateStartType);

Allan

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2  [System.DateTime,LatencyApp.Domain.Models.ChartHist],<>f__AnonymousType2`1[System.DateTime]]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

My Code:

```
        DateTime appChartDateStart = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime appChartDateEnd = DateTime.MinValue;
        var dateStartType = from row in myRow
                                group row by row.LoginDateTime_Rounded into g
                                select new { MinDateTime = g.Min(row => row.LoginDateTime_Rounded) };
        var dateEndType = from row in myRow
                                group row by row.LoginDateTime_Rounded into g
                                select new { MinDateTime = g.Max(row => row.LoginDateTime_Rounded) };
        appChartDateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dateStartType);
        appChartDateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEndType);
        TimeSpan difAppChart = appChartDateEnd - appChartDateStart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it in the LINQ sintax, it worked pretty well, and a bit cleaner too:

```
DateTime appChartDateStart = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime appChartDateEnd = DateTime.MinValue;

var dateStartType = myRow.GroupBy(x => x.LoginDateTime_Rounded).Select(x => x.Key).Min();
var dateEndType = myRow.GroupBy(x => x.LoginDateTime_Rounded).Select(x => x.Key).Max();

TimeSpan difAppChart = appChartDateEnd - appChartDateStart;
```

Completed Code:

```
        DateTime appChartDateStart = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime appChartDateEnd = DateTime.MinValue;
        if (histByApp.Count() != 0)
        {
            var dateStartType = histByApp.GroupBy(x => x.LoginDateTime_Rounded).Select(x => x.Key).Min();
            var dateEndType = histByApp.GroupBy(x => x.LoginDateTime_Rounded).Select(x => x.Key).Max();
            appChartDateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dateStartType);
            appChartDateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEndType);
        }
        TimeSpan difAppChart = appChartDateEnd - appChartDateStart;
```

Comment: Edit your answer and include it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your select is creating an anonymous type with a property MinDateTime. The Convert.TomDateTime method does not know how to convert this anonymous type. Try doing:

```
DateTime appChartDateStart = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime appChartDateEnd = DateTime.MinValue;
var dateStartType = (from row in myRow
                        group row by row.LoginDateTime_Rounded into g
                        select new { MinDateTime = g.Min(row => row.LoginDateTime_Rounded) }).FirstOrDefault();
var dateEndType = (from row in myRow
                        group row by row.LoginDateTime_Rounded into g
                        select new { MinDateTime = g.Max(row => row.LoginDateTime_Rounded) }).FirstOrDefault();
appChartDateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dateStartType);
appChartDateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEndType);
TimeSpan difAppChart = appChartDateEnd - appChartDateStart;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That does not compile for me.

Comment: Ah right, I forgot it is a collection vs single object. Try my modified code.